# what is unsupported file given on command line

Tags: command-line, software-installation, deb

Trying to install protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3_all.deb using  sudo apt-get install.  terminal responds: E: Unsupported file ///home/george/Downloads given on commandline

```
$ sudo apt-get install ///home/george/Downloads protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3_all.deb
[sudo] password for george: 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file ///home/george/Downloads given on commandline
```

protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3_all.deb is definatly in download file on the computer

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Contact the maker of the VPN they have their own support.

Comment: The maker of the VPN, Proton provided an answer that is unusable to me in my present state of tech.

Comment: If the .deb file is located in your downloads directory, then you need to separate the path and the filename with a `/` not a space: `sudo apt-get install /home/george/Downloads/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.3_all.deb`

Comment: It seems like you're trying to install a .deb file the same way as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/), but your syntax is incorrect.